# The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to use crystal reports in my windows application.I am using vs2010.

I have already installed SAP Crystal Report for visual studio 2010.

Now I have just added one blank report to my application.But When I build the project I got some errors of following

**The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be 
found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: I changed the tags on your question because they were wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier Application's target framework was pointing to ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile".

**Then I just changed it to ".Net Framework 4".**

And error got Disappeared.